# INSERT...SELECT query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
`user1`
- full_name
- headline # this is empty

`user2`
- full_name
- headline # this has content
```

I want to insert the `headline` from `user2` table into `user1` table. This is what I have so far:

```
insert into user1 set headline = (select headline from user2 where headline=headline)
```

However, I get an error message from this saying the select returns more than one row. How would I correctly issue this insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do.  In particular, what happens when there are multiple records in each table?  If you want to copy the headline from `user2` into `user1` where the `full_name` matches, you can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables and update `user1`:

```
UPDATE user1 JOIN user2 USING (full_name) SET user1.headline = user2.headline
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want an INSERT then you want

```
INSERT INTO user1 SELECT full_name, headline
```

If you're actually trying to UPDATE then you want

```
UPDATE user1 SET headline = (SELECT headline FROM user2 WHERE user1.full_name = user2.full_name)
```